# Как прослушивать несколько пользователей mqtt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt

На питоне подписываюсь на mqtt broker mosquitto. Установила пользователя и пароль. Но можно ли, чтобы этот топик слушался двумя и более пользователями. Вот пример кода

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):  # The callback for when the client connects to the broker
    print("Connected with result code {0}".format(str(rc)))  # Print result of connection attempt

    client.subscribe("digitest/test")  # Subscribe to the topic вЂњdigitest/test1вЂќ, receive any messages published on it

def on_message(client, userdata, msg): 
    print("Message received-> " + msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))  

client = mqtt.Client() 
client.on_connect = on_connect  
client.on_message = on_message  
client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60) 

#client.connect('', 17300)

client.loop_forever()  # Start networking daemon
```

Answer (score 0):

Протокол MQTT является широковещательным и все клиенты, подписанные на топик, будут получать сообщения. Для этого и существует mqtt-broker, который и берет на себя задачу принимать сообщения и рассылать их **всем клиентам** подписанныи на этот топик.

Это выглядит так. Вы создаете еще одного клиента, который также подключен к этому брокеру и подписываете его на тот же топик. В вашем случае это `digitest/test`.